# how to pass the multiple values from one view to another view using session mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, view

In my first page, i have list of amounts column related to that plan. if i click one column it redirects to the another page.. In that page, i want to show the amount what i click before. I never used session before. Now i tried. but it is always showing single amount only.. i don't know how to create session for multiple values..

***controller***

```
        Session["rs360"] = "Rs. 360";
        Session["rs1000"] = "Rs. 1000";
        Session["rs1500"] = "Rs. 1500";
```

***View***

```
 <div><%:Session["rs360"] %></div>
```

***Actual view(Index.Cshtml)***

```
 <div id="rs360">
    <span class="font18">Rs.360</span> 
 </div>

<a href="<%: Url.Action("Payment", "Home") %>"><img src="../../Content/Images/Subscribe now on click.png" class="btn" onclick="return sms_confirm1()" /></a>

<div id="rs1000">
  <span class="font18">Rs.1000</span> 
 </div>

<a href="<%: Url.Action("Payment", "Home") %>"><img src="../../Content/Images/Subscribe now on click.png" class="btn" onclick="return sms_confirm1()" /></a>
```

when click the button it goes to another view called **Payment**

```
 <td>
   <a class="callpickupcash" href="<%: Url.Action("ElectronicTransfer", "Home") %>"><img src="/Content/Images/ebanking.png" class="Featured-plan"></a>
 </td>
```

when click this above button it will open one popup menu... At that menu i should show the amount value..

Here Only i passed the following session what i already declare at top

```
<div><%:Session["rs360"] %></div>
```

Here i gave the session variable so my result is showing 360. but when i click 1000 it should change.. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question by using localStorage() function..

I passed the radiobuttons for values like

```
<%:html.radiobutton("smscount",500,true)%>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function sms_confirm() {

       var amount = $("input:radio[name=smscount]:checked").val();
       localStorage.setItem("smscount", amount);
       if (r == false) {
           return false;
       }

   }
```

**Redirect page**

Here I am showing the values into the textbox. so i take the textbox id..

```
$(function () {
          var textbox = $('#Amount');
          var checkValue = localStorage.getItem("smscount")
          textbox.val(checkValue);

      });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using session for anything else, I suggest to you that for this problem you don't need session.  You can simply pass the clicked amount to the action method that you are calling with that link, and then incorporate that amount back into the model you are passing to the second view.  You can do that by using viewData or even better by having the view strongly typed to a view model that contains that information.

**Edit**

OK. Let me see if I got this right. The link on the first view that is rendered with:

```
Url.Action("Payment", "EmployerVas")
```

Calls a Payment method in EmployerVas that renders a view (view2) that contains a button rendered with:

Url.Action("ElectronicTransfer", "EmployerVas","Employer")

That will open up a popup menu and you want the value clicked on in the first view to show up in the popup. If that is what you are trying to do and without changing too much in what you are doing and moving you to a viewModel based system, I would change the following:

```
 Url.Action("Payment", "EmployerVas", new{amount="360"})
```

Change the Payment method in the EmployerVas controller to accept an input parameter of type int or long or whatever meets your needs.

Then you can either store that in the session if you need to and pass it to view2 and then in view2 change the link again to pass that value (or if you want to use the value stored in the session then leave link as is):

```
Url.Action("ElectronicTransfer", EmployerVas","amountToSHow=sessionOrViewDataPassedValue")
```

Now since the value is in the session you can use it or you can change the ElectronicTransfer method to accept an input value of the same type as above and named amountToShow then you can pass it to the popup.

Comment: I never stored that amount anyway.. i want to take it dynamically. And also i am not clicking that amount.. i just click the button for that amount.

Comment: Same thing. Just pass the amount to the method called by that button. You don't need to store it. Just pass it along from one view to another.

Comment: I am very new to this concept. if u give examples it will better to do.

Comment: Please post your cshtml files especially for the view with the buttons on it and I will do my best to help you from there.